# Python issues if/elif

Tags: python

I'm trying to make this code work but I can't seem to find the right solution.

```
while True:
    tname = input("Please enter the unit of the temperature: ")
    list=["Celsius","Kelvin","Fahrenheit"]
    if tname == list[0] or list[1] or list[2]:
        break
    elif tname is not list[0] or list[1] or list[2]:
        print("Not a valid unit. Please try again.")
```

I want the program to stop whenever either Celsius, Kelvin or Fahrenheit is typed but the program stops regardless of what I write. Do you guys know to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: `if tname == list[0] or list[1] or list[2]:` is not interpreted by Python as it would be in English. Maybe `if tname == list[0] or tname == list[1] or tname == list[2]:`

Comment: I can't seem to find any of the 100 dupes for this question...

Comment: @TreytenCarey it is valid code

Comment: @MadPhysicist I actually sat and read the dupe title 5 times to make a mental note :P

Comment: @roganjosh. Thanks for the tip. I just did the same :)

Answer (score 1):

The technically correct answer is that chaining comprehensions doesn't work like that; you have to do

```
if tname == list[0] or tname == list[1] or tname == list[2]:
```

But have you considered using `in`?

```
if tname in list:
```

or similarly:

```
if tname not in list:
```

Also, I'd advise against using `list` as the name of your list, as that's also the name of a type!

Comment: This code is way simpler and easier to understand, and the best part is that it works :D Thanks a lot!